# Flash loading first external swf loaded

Tags: actionscript-3, loading, display

I am making an application to test art from a game I volunteered for. Right now the example I am posting will only touch the armors but the loading process is the same throughout the program. I have a movieclip ready to hold the loaded file but it adds it to the container via the class. It works how it should however my issue is that if you use another file with the same classes then it will default to the first file loaded. Even i use loaderr.unloadAndStop() and remove everything from the stage, it will always load the first file that corresponds to the class I am loading by. Since the armor pieces are loaded by class it makes it a hassle to test multiple changes to an armor file without changing the classes on each export. Here is an example of the code that is being used and I am curious if there is any way that I can improve this. `

```
public class Test extends MovieClip
{
    public var mcChar:Display;
    public var btnTest:SimpleButton;
    public var btnTest2:SimpleButton;
    public var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
    public var strSkinLinkage:String;
    public var strGender:String;

    public function Test()
    {
        btnTest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, TestP);
        btnTest2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, TestP2);
    }

    public function TestP(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        mcChar = new Display();
        stage.addChild(mcChar);
        mcChar.x = 789.6;
        mcChar.y = 604.75;
        mcChar.width = 667.15;
        mcChar.height = 478.55;
        strSkinLinkage = "CNC";
        strGender = "M"
        this.ldr.load(new URLRequest("CNC.SWF"), new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
        this.ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.onLoadSkinComplete);
    }
    public function TestP2(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        mcChar = new Display();
        stage.addChild(mcChar);
        mcChar.x = 789.6;
        mcChar.y = 604.75;
        mcChar.width = 667.15;
        mcChar.height = 478.55;
        strSkinLinkage = "CNC";
        strGender = "M"
        this.ldr.load(new URLRequest("CNC2.SWF"), new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
        this.ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.onLoadSkinComplete);
    }

    public function onLoadSkinComplete(e:Event):*
    {
        var AssetClass:Class;
        try
        {
            AssetClass = (getDefinitionByName(((strSkinLinkage + strGender) + "Head")) as Class);
            mcChar.head.addChildAt(new (AssetClass)(), 0);
        }
        catch(err:Error)
        {
            AssetClass = (getDefinitionByName(("mcHead" + strGender)) as Class);
            mcChar.head.addChildAt(new (AssetClass)(), 0);
        };
        AssetClass = (getDefinitionByName(((strSkinLinkage + strGender) + "Chest")) as Class);
        chest.addChild(ldr.content (AssetClass)());
        mcChar.chest.addChild(new (chest)());
        this.ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.onLoadSkinComplete);
    }
}
```

`
I don't think its well formatted on this site but this is the core code. I have separate removal functions and my imports are all there. Like I said I cant seem to get it to format correctly. This is my test scenario and isn't my full dynamic tester where I can choose the file. Any help in figuring out how to use the most recent file is appreciated. Also for some background I am more of a self taught novice in as3.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. If the problem is that loaded assets get mixed because they have same class names, you should load your libraries into different **ApplicationDomain**s (look into the second argument: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load() ) then use **Loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(...)** method.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the response and it partly works to my understanding. I updated the loading functions to include a different appDomain per function. The  issue that I can see happening is the ability to dynamically create appDomains per each load of the file. Since it is a tester, it is used to repeatedly test multiple iterations of a file with the same class. It will switch between the two files successfully in my test setup but beyond that to a dynamic loader that might reload 50 different files 5 - 6 times until the Tester is reset. Thank you and I was wondering if more can be done.

Comment: Thinking about it. Would it be possible just to create a new separate domains per upload so each file has its own domain then destroy the old one once a new one is created.

Comment: I don't see how it is a problem to create new application domain for each file. Also, if it is a separate domain, the **unloadAndStop(...)** method can completely remove the loaded content (if you load them into the same application domain, they get mixed with the main application and cannot be unloaded and removed completely).

Comment: I am unsure how to dynamically create a new app domain for each file when uploaded it. Also unloadAndStop(..) doesnt seem to remove the file from a different app domain in terms of uploading another file with the same class and it still displaying the fist file. Unless loading two files with the same class makes it get mixed. Anyhow I am unsure but I am thinking somehow making a random number generator with a large range as the domain creator but i am unsure how to plug that into actually making it an application domain. Again thank you for your responses! They really help a lot.

Comment: **Loader.load("myfile.swf", new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)));** - that will create a new domain that is a child of the current one, so you will load any SWF into its own application domain while not falling into the cross-domain issues.

Comment: Ok you are super amazing. I don't think I would have ever thought of the App(App.curr) in a million years! This loader function combined with the loader.contentLoaderInfo.appDomain.getDefintion is exactly the answer that improves this by 1000%. I don't think I can choose comments as answers so if you want to add an answer with both those functions, I can mark your answer as what was needed. Thank a million again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it gets to loading and unloading assets in AS3, there are several things to learn.

[ApplicationDomain](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html) is a container for class definitions. The [getDefinitionByName(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()) method is basically the same as calling the [ApplicationDomain.getDefinition(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition()) on the current **ApplicationDomain** (or maybe on the main **ApplicationDomain**, I never tried to do it in the loaded content). As the side result, you cannot have two classes with the same names inside the same **ApplicationDomain** (or rather you can, but one of them is inaccessible, who knows).

When you load another SWF which falls into the "same domain" category (same **www** domain, or same/nested local folder), AS3 automatically mixes all the definitions from the loaded SWF into the main **ApplicationDomain**. If you are willing to have some advanced control over loading/unloading stuff, or/and there are "skin" libraries that have similar sets of classes, you need to put the loaded files into separate **ApplicationDomain**s or their definitions will collide and the result will be unpredictable (yet obviously not satisfactory).

The [Loader.load(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load()) method has a second argument that allows you to do so:

```
// If there are no mandatory constructor arguments,
// you are free to omit the () brackets. I like doing so.
var aLoader:Loader = new Loader;
var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mylibrary.swf");

// Documentation states that passing no argument here is
// the same as passing ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.
var childDomain:ApplicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain;
var aContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, childDomain);

aLoader.load(aRequest, aContext);
```

Thus, when external SWF library is loaded, you can obtain its classes/definitions as following:

```
var aClass:Class;

// If you get things from the loaded SWF's Library
// then it is Sprite or MovieClip for the most cases.
var anAsset:Sprite;

aClass = aLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("MyAssetClass") as Class;
anAsset = new aClass;
```

When you do not longer need some of the loaded libraries, you call the [Loader.unloadAndStop(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop()) method on the relevant **Loader** instance. Combined with the loading SWF into separate **ApplicationDomain** you can be sure that all of the loaded content (graphics, classes, sounds) is unloaded, destroyed and removed (that one I actually checked):

```
// Passing "true" also forces the Garbage Collector
// to actually do its job for a change.
aLoader.unloadAndStop(true);
```