# Loaded SWF's wont preform their functions in air

Tags: security, actionscript-3, air

Back for some help! So I am making an AIR application that loads SWF's into a container to be viewed by the user. However when I load the files into their containers, the SWF's that are loaded are unable to execute their own code. IE press an invisible button on the loaded SWF and it changes colour. I tried to google solutions for this since Security.allowDomain("*"); is throwing this error in flash. However from what I have read, AIR doesn't allow loaded swfs to execute code for some security reason but im not 100% sure on that either.

```
SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.
at flash.system::Security$/allowDomain()
at BugFree()[D:\Desktop\BugFree\BugFree.as:72]
```

Without the Allow domain it throws this security error when attempting to click the invisible button.

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'file:///D:/Desktop/Rewritten Tester/TechDemoSwordNew.swf' 
tried to access incompatible context 'app:/BugFree.swf'
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'file:///D:/Desktop/Rewritten Tester/TechDemoSwordNew.swf' 
tried to access incompatible context 'app:/BugFree.swf'
SecurityError: Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: parent: 
file:///D:/Desktop/Rewritten Tester/TechDemoSwordNew.swf cannot access 
app:/BugFree.swf.
at flash.display::DisplayObject/get parent()
at TechDemoSwordNew_fla::Button_Play_21/onButtonPress()
```

This only shows in the Animate output bar. When I publish it, with application with runtime embeded, and open the exe it throws no errors but the invisible button still doesnt work.

Here is the code for the swf being loaded.

```
btnButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonPress, false, 0, true);
function onButtonPress(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(parent).play();
}
stop();
```

This is timeline code within the button since that is how the game company who put my item in game did it. I originally submitted it with it all done in classes but that is besides the point. When the button is pressed the loaded SWF should play and then stop. But I get the above mentioned Sandbox violation.

The code used to load the SWF is below

```
public function WeaponLoad()
    {
        if(FileMenu.WeaponFileTxt.text != "")
        {
            LoadWeapon(FileMenu.WeaponFile.nativePath);
        }
        else if(FileMenu.WeaponFileTxt.text == "")
        {
            Character.mcChar.weapon.removeChildAt(0);
            Character.mcChar.weaponOff.removeChildAt(0);
        }
    }

public function LoadWeapon(strFilePath: String)
    {
        WeaponLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, CompleteWeaponLoad);
        WeaponLoader.load(new URLRequest(strFilePath), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)));
    }

public function CompleteWeaponLoad(e: Event)
    {
        var WeaponClass: Class;
        if (MiscMenu.WeaponSelect.MainClick.currentFrame != 3)
        {
            try
            {
                trace("WeaponOff");
                WeaponClass = WeaponLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(FileMenu.WeaponLinkTxt.text) as Class;
                this.Character.mcChar.weapon.removeChildAt(0);
                this.Character.mcChar.weaponOff.removeChildAt(0);
                this.Character.mcChar.weapon.addChild(new(WeaponClass)());
            }
            catch (err: Error)
            {
                trace("Either the weapon class doesnt exist or it is wrong");
                this.Character.mcChar.weapon.removeChildAt(0);
                this.Character.mcChar.weaponOff.removeChildAt(0);
            }
        }
        else if (MiscMenu.WeaponSelect.MainClick.currentFrame == 3)
        {
            try
            {
                WeaponClass = WeaponLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(FileMenu.WeaponLinkTxt.text) as Class;
                this.Character.mcChar.weapon.removeChildAt(0);
                this.Character.mcChar.weaponOff.removeChildAt(0);
                this.Character.mcChar.weapon.addChild(new(WeaponClass)());
                this.Character.mcChar.weaponOff.addChild(new(WeaponClass)());
            }
            catch (err: Error)
            {
                trace("Either the weapon class doesnt exist or it is wrong");
                this.Character.mcChar.weapon.removeChildAt(0);
                this.Character.mcChar.weaponOff.removeChildAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be apreciated since I have no idea how to change any security sandbox settings within the publish settings since it is greyed out for me. Like I said I tried googling it but I couldn't seem to come up with any answers. Also worth noting is im a self taught novice and I do not know a lot of things in regards to AS3. I know my codes could be cleaner and I plan to clean it up and properly reduce memory consumption once I have the base program up and running. Thank you for the help!

Comment: The setup is not clear. You are loading something, but there's no telling how it is related to the provided code. Also, is that thing you do acting differently in debug (or browser) environment, rather than AIR? If no, the AIR part is irrelevant. Basically, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then edit your question appropriately.

Comment: Edited it to show the errors, what the code is, what I have done and should hopefully be an appropriate question now! Sorry for the terrible questioning earlier. Was in a hurry to get it submitted before I had to leave.

Comment: Is this code **MovieClip(parent).play();**  placed on main timeline of the loaded SWF?

Comment: No, its placed within the button movieclip. The button is placed in the movieclip with the animations in it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not setting the application domain properly. Here is the code included in as3 documentation:

```
 var loader:Loader = new Loader();
 var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("[file path].swf");
 var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
 loader.load(url, loaderContext);
```

Use it in your *LoadWeapon* function.

In the meantime try not to use Uppercase letters for starting variables and method names. In ActionScript names starting with Uppercase represent Class names. It will widely improve readability of your code.

Comment: Doesn't this do the same thing as the load function besides the null. Like I get this is probably cleaner but I am confused as to how this would solve the issue of the security sandbox prevent the loaded SWF code from executing.

Comment: No, it isn't the same. You are passing the current domain as parrent domain to constructor of ApplicationDomain, that is unnecesary and probably wrong. I can't test your code to see if it leads to the same result but in theory those are not the same.

Comment: Well the code you posted still yields the same security error. And the reason my code has the "wrong" app domain is because it creates a new app domain for every file loaded. Since it is to test SWF's multiple SWF's with the same class could be loaded but the art or look may change in between them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940810/flash-loading-first-external-swf-loaded/51966245#51966245

Comment: Sigh, sorry to hear that. Though I didn't know you are loading multiple SWFs with conflicting class names. Your idea to load a SWF and use its classes to instantiate same clips with different assets actually sounds hackish! What have get you to do so?

Comment: Is _FileMenu.WeaponLinkTxt.text_ the name for the MovieClip that contains `MovieClip(parent).play();`? If it's true, you are instantiating that clip and adding it to your main app, then the _parent_ would be some container from your main app that the loaded object doesn't have access to call its play() method.

Comment: 1.Loaded MovieCLip(Has the animations)
2.Play button movieclip is on a layer in the movieclip with animations
3.MovieClip(parent).play(); is in the play button movieclip timeline alone.

So I can see where it might be targeting a container for the app but I am looking for a solution to that XD As far as it being hackish. Im building the app as an art tester for a flash game. Right now im focusing on the dev sided people who would get a lot of use out o it. Hopefully revive the community a bit. Their code to do it like that. Im just trying to get it all working.

Comment: So i just added one more layer of movieclips and it works now but I cant expect any normal user to do that just to get it to work in the tester. Is there any way to have the parent actually access the container from my app security wise. Looking to create as little hassle for the users as I can.

Comment: Have you tried `Loader.loadBytes()` instead of `Loader.load()`? Give it try, read your swf bytes into a **ByteArray**, for example using `FileStream.readBytes()`, then load it via **loadBytes** and make sure to set `LoaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;`

Comment: Can you link to some documentation or provide samples xD I'm not the best in as3. o.o

Comment: `var file: File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("myFile.swf");
var fileStream: FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var swfBytes: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
fileStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
fileStream.close();

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteReadingFile);
var loaderContext: LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, null, null);
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
loader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);`

Comment: Alright ill give it a try. Thanks a lot. Its almost 4 am right now so ill let you know when I wake up. If you wanna submit this in the answer form so others can see it clearly then ill accept it once I test it out to make sure it works! Ill keep you posted on the results

Comment: So good morning :D I'm not sure it solves your problem, but loadBytes works better when you have security problems while loading external SWFs, give it a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: You got a discord we could chat at?

Comment: no unfortunately I don't. whats up? did you get it to work?

Comment: Haven;t had time to do it yet since ive been busy with college. However I was wondering about the app domains since I need a new one per loaded file so the same class name per item tested but with different changes to the item art can be tested without refreshing the program. Would my current app domain set up and put that in the loader context work with this? If so then I can try it out this friday.

Comment: OK, you can creat a new ApplicationDomain for every loader, use this code to create the loader context: var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain), null);

Comment: Ignore the ping. Was gonna show an error but was unnecessary

Comment: Ok. I actually got it working. Didn't need the file stream. Thanks for the pointers however. A buddy finally hit me up after a week of silence.

Short hand version is loading file through Url Loader with the data format as binary.Set the byte array as the Url loader data. Load the bytes with the context. If you have a way for me to PM you so you can add another answer with how I did it so you can get the answer credit since you pretty much posted everything that was used and really gave me all the helpful information and sent me in the right direction with the examples! Thank you btw a bunch

Comment: Ok and I lied lol. The loading works but it seems like it is still using the same application domain with your application domain set up? Even though it should be a new one per load?

Comment: And solved. Looks like the loader context needs to be assigned in the loading function and not the main class. Ignore my alarms xD Apparently im just not thinking tonight after 8 hours at college. Though the only issue is im not getting an error about a function that should be existing. Since I havent added it to my main class air tells me a variable or term is undefined upon loading the item. That was an intended error until I added the colour change option but now it isn't showing up. Does doing this stop the errors from showing? ONly seems to show up when I force another error on loading.

Comment: Forcing the loading error pretty much means i give it the wrong definition for getDefinition forcing it to use the the default head in my library on error loads. That head is asking for the function but not the loaded armor.

                                     Edit. JK I need some coffee. Didn't ask for it in my unfixed version. Just loaded the version before coding changes. Ignore me :( Sorry for the pings and confusion.

Comment: Congrats! Nice you got the byteArray from urlLoader data. And yes, I'm little bit confused. Is there any problem right now that I help you with?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you bundle your swfs with the AIR app and use File class to load them? If you want to use classes from the swfs, maybe consider making swc library?

Comment: Nope. The issue is that it is for testing new SWF's that are being made every day.